# Front page message in wrong language

Tags: bug, status-completed, hot-questions, homepage, localization

See image below, I don't remember what this text should be, but it was in English the last time I went to the site.  (rev 2013.12.16.1237 - not sure about this number, I might have copied the wrong window)

[image: bug]

Comment: FYI "Hot Network Questions" is the original text!

Comment: I don't see this on `rev *.1237`

Comment: lol Brazil is taking over the rest

Comment: @Pëkka - Because Brazil is "Hot, hot, hot"?

Comment: No repro here..

Comment: @ChristmasUnicorn - I can't reproduce it too... I think it must be already fixed.... I did a control refresh before I posted, honest!\

Comment: Which SE site is this?

Comment: @AmalMurali - SO

Comment: `status-nonrepro`, sorry :(

Comment: @AmalMurali - That is not a problem, I'm happy to have it fixed.  Like most Americans I get scared when I see text on a web page that is not English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oops.  This was cached in our global cache without respect for language in the cache key.  It's fixed in the next build (rolling out now).

I'm sure there are more of these we never thought of since it wasn't a problem before...they'll be fun.

Comment: But what determines what language we see? Why nobody else saw it?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It depends on whether the very first request to a server that has an empty cache goes to br.so or anywhere else. The latter is of course much more probable.

Comment: @balpha - I guess I got "Lucky"